# Increase TextInputLayout focused text size

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I am trying to increase text size of hint in `TextInputLayout` while `EditText` is in focus. But not able to figure out how to do the same.

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/component_margin"
            >
              <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/firstName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_first_name"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text"
                    android:maxLength="25"
                    android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme"
                     />
 </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="normal_text">14sp</dimen>
```

styles.xml

```
 <style name="EditTextTheme">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:labelTextSize">@dimen/input_text_size</item>
 </style>
```

> I want to increase size of Email shown in image for bigger screen devices.

[image]

> Similarly for Password

[image]

Comment: try adding this in xml    `android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
`

Comment: Tried this with Medium, Large. But had no  effect in output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the default hintTextAppearance for TextInputLayout. Working fine for me

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_Email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivLogoLogin"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium">
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your styles:

```
<style name="InputTextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
```

And then TextInputLayout in your layout file should look like this:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/InputTextLabel"
            android:minHeight="30dp">
```

Comment: Tried, but didnt worked. The output is same.  My activity theme is <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">